# Java : Method return Issue

Tags: java, methods, return

Hi there I have created a class to run another Test class but I am facing some problems.
I have declared  both the agePremium and ticketPremium as private doubles. I later on use them in 2 methods to calculate the premium respectively. But when it gets to the part where i want t use the calculated variables in another calculation here

```
/* 
public double premium() {

    if (ticket <4){
        return ((BASE_PREMIUM*value) * agePremium) * ticketPremium;
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("Sorry, you have too many tickets !!");
        return 0;
    }
} 
*/
```

it does not read the values from my methods and instead reads the 1 from the declaration and initialization.

private double agePremium =1;
private double ticketPremium =1;

and it multiplies them.

How do i get them to link them to each other and replace the 1 with the new values and multiply. Thanks

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Driver {
    private int age;
    private int ticket;
    private double value;
    final double BASE_PREMIUM=0.05;
    private double agePremium =1;
    private double ticketPremium =1;


    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    public void read() {

        System.out.println("Driver’s Age?");
        age = scanner.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Number of Tickets?");
        ticket = scanner.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Value of Car?");
        value = scanner.nextDouble();
    }   

    public double premium() {

        if (ticket <4){
            return ((BASE_PREMIUM*value)*agePremium)*ticketPremium;
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("Sorry, you have too many tickets !!");
            return 0;
        }
    }   



    public void premiumAge() {
        if (age > 29) {
            agePremium += 0;
        }
        else if (age <= 29 && age >= 25) {
            agePremium += 0.10;
        }
        else {
            agePremium += 0.15;
        }
    }

    public void premiumTicket() {
        switch (ticket) {
        case '1':
            ticketPremium += 0.1;
            break;
        case '2':
            ticketPremium += 0.25;
            break;
        case '3':
            ticketPremium += 0.50;
            break;
        case '0':
            ticketPremium += 0.00;
        default:
            ticketPremium = 0.00;
            break;
        }
    }           
}
```

Comment: Did you call your `premium()` and `premiumAge()`? If so, show the code  where you're instantiating the `Driver`

Comment: Just wondering what `agePremium += 0;` is suppose to do?

Comment: @Pshemo Pretty awesome huh?

Comment: @JuanMendes Yea. I am shocked. Just like when I learned that meaning of life is 42.

Answer (score 1):

Your methods should be somewhat like this, returning a `double` in order to access the private data fields in another class

```
public double premiumAge() {
    if ...
        return agePremium;
    else if ...
        return ....
    ...
}
```

You need to return a value to use the method in another class, if you're expecting a value.
Also good to note is naming convention.  When you want methods to access a private data field, use the name of the data field with a prefix of `get` eg. `agePremium` : `getAgePremium()`;

**To Access From another class**

```
Driver driver = new Driver(); // create a Driver object (instantiate)
System.out.println(driver.premiumAge());

// Or if you follow the naming convention in your Driver class
System.out.println(driver.getAgePremium());
```

Comment: Looks like you actually decrypted what the code was trying to do

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot to invoke methods `premiumAge()` and `premiumTicket()`.

They seem to be the ones modifying `agePremium` and `ticketPremium`.

Answer (score 0):

Somewhere along the way, you'll need to call `premiumAge()` and `premiumTicket()`, to get the calculation to happen.  Probably from somewhere in the `premium()` method would be a good idea.

Note that keeping the calculated values in fields is not as good an idea as having the methods that calculate them actually return their results.